# Ruta de Laravel no encontrada, pero si esta definida

Tags: php, laravel-5

he definido una ruta en el archivo de rutas web de Laravel:

```
// Rutas para el Product
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
Route::get('/product/download', 'ProductController@download')->name('product.download');
```

El metodo **download** si existe en el controlador:

[image: método download esta definido en el ProductController]

Pero cuando intendo acceder a la ruta con nombre **product.download** me arroja el error 404 de ruta no encontrada.

[image: ruta no encontrada]

¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

Comment: Suponiendo que la parte del frontend está correcta (ya que no has puesto el código de esta, ni la estructura de archivos..), has probado el comando **php artisan route:cache** ?